# Adding DNS server entry using .CSV file

Tags: powershell, dns

I want to add the DNS server entries A, CNAME, TXT and MX only. No need for SOA and NS records.

This is the example of the .CSV file https://pastebin.pl/view/12ae3d2a

The goal here is to be able to create those A, CNAME, TXT and MX records only in bulk.

Code:

```
$DomainNames = Get-Content -Path C:\DNS\Input.csv
$PrimaryDNSServer = 'PRDINTDNS07-VM'

$DomainNames | ForEach-Object {
    # Check the existence in the primary DNS server before proceeding, if exist, then proceed
    $dnsZone = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $PrimaryDNSServer -Name $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If ($dnsZone) {
        Write-Host "DNS Forward Lookup Zones $($domainName.Name) exist in $($PrimaryDNSServer)" -ForegroundColor Green
        Try {
            #Verify the DNS Zone in Primary DNS server
            $dnsZone | Select-Object -Property ZoneName, ZoneType, ZoneFile, DynamicUpdate, IsReadOnly, SecondaryServers | Format-Table -AutoSize

            $splat = @{
                ComputerName = $PrimaryDNSServer
                ZoneName     = $domainName.Name
                ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
            }

            switch ($_.Type) {
                A {
                    Write-Host "Adding A record $($_.Type) = $($_.Value)"
                    Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA @splat -Name $_.Name -IPv4Address $_.Value.Trim() -WhatIf
                }
                TXT {
                    Write-Host "Adding TXT Record $($_.Type) = $($_.Value)"
                    Add-DnsServerResourceRecord @splat -Name '.' -Txt -DescriptiveText $_.Value.Trim() -WhatIf
                }
                MX {
                    Write-Host "Adding MX preference $($_.Type) = $($_.Value)"
                    Add-DnsServerResourceRecordMX @splat -Name '.' -MailExchange $_.Value.split(':')[0] -Preference $_.Value.split(':')[1] -TimeToLive 01:00:00 -WhatIf
                }
            }
            
            #Verify the newly created entry & NS server records in Primary DNS
            Get-DnsServerResourceRecord @splat | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Warning -Message "Something wrong happened in creating DNS record for Forward Lookup Zones $($domainName.Name) in $($PrimaryDNSServer)"
            Write-Warning -Message $_.Exception.Message
            Get-DnsServerResourceRecord @splat | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "DNS Forward Lookup Zones $($domainName.Name) does not exist in $($PrimaryDNSServer)" -ForegroundColor Red
        Continue
    }
}
```

This is the code as .CSV sample:

```
Name    Type    Value
hotel.com   SOA pdns1.ultradns.net
hotel.com   A   204.74.99.101
hotel.com   MX  mail.hotels.com:10
hotel.com   NS  pdns1.ultradns.net
hotel.com   NS  pdns2.ultradns.net
hotel.com   NS  pdns3.ultradns.org
hotel.com   NS  pdns4.ultradns.org
hotel.com   NS  pdns5.ultradns.info
hotel.com   NS  pdns6.ultradns.co.uk
yahoonews.com   SOA hidden-master.yahoo.com
yahoonews.com   A   74.6.136.150
yahoonews.com   A   98.136.103.23
yahoonews.com   A   212.82.100.150
yahoonews.com   MX  mxa-00505701.gslb.pphosted.com:10
yahoonews.com   MX  mxb-00505701.gslb.pphosted.com:10
yahoonews.com   TXT google-site-verification=AWTjNddXqEm2s7SA6JKE50bc1KvGefM75KCZ9CTIkZg
yahoonews.com   TXT docusign=b6c182db-3a2b-4eed-9f23-34df23813e4e
yahoonews.com   TXT knowbe4-site-verification=bc3830115833f4f956e30f506f1da8c8
yahoonews.com   TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com -all
yahoonews.com   TXT dropbox-domain-verification=qn36yaodrl8o
yahoonews.com   NS  ns1.yahoo.com
yahoonews.com   NS  ns2.yahoo.com
yahoonews.com   NS  ns3.yahoo.com
yahoonews.com   NS  ns4.yahoo.com
yahoonews.com   NS  ns5.yahoo.com
booking.com SOA ns0.bkngs.com
booking.com A   5.57.16.220
booking.com MX  mxa-0032a201.gslb.pphosted.com:10
booking.com MX  mxb-0032a201.gslb.pphosted.com:10
booking.com TXT MS=ms35392088
booking.com TXT VkJHqtn1JPDHrgqwzb8C30fmoABFhxVfjIOtLvlUK06CUwKgd2mevDGtnDhWZcNbxEgK39DOezbHay8XSv1zVQ==
booking.com TXT _globalsign-domain-verification=9Xqu2bonefjuoUF-XmyjAptAfuE-yStJz6wy9UnH-C
booking.com TXT _globalsign-domain-verification=FSlSaYMuHsffF-JRsSpJSonQOV0_jwrwl5kQGpFdtb
booking.com TXT _globalsign-domain-verification=l_BNpBAnk-rKZRyXJ9UkBfv9o6EEuuenkBrGpYNYo0
booking.com TXT adobe-idp-site-verification=040db58f-cfb9-4203-a555-bfcd15b24b86
booking.com TXT atlassian-domain-verification=F3hugs/a4ZZHwjGTLmlb12IMA3TIRiz3ifqw4TKRz9tWk0LoyBBXfwc775aT/juy
booking.com TXT cisco-ci-domain-verification=18ab0a696c72c79cc3e9c35ddca9a4d722c40bdb86e06aa25aefe1d8284d0946
booking.com TXT docusign=1ddc2bf3-a249-4127-a351-f22dc75077d3
booking.com TXT globalsign-domain-verification=jpcnVg6kuHYyEz5op6ZzxI2E53gePoVqca7RgL0aNq
booking.com TXT google-site-verification=IqETr3m1Iq2apdhg2tJndtOH5xn_C0PrLSBL4UpB9WU
booking.com TXT google-site-verification=WMDRc5NQqj7RWff1N8L0_Ikc08kSr-iUa3C0Zczl9QA
booking.com TXT google-site-verification=w40NMRtPNbdzr8FXV33gtkD3qlFHastApR2UgHgggf8
booking.com TXT google-site-verification=z4muhl35r1aT-msc5R269PO3RKaZHc7zzn6omxkiedI
booking.com TXT logmein-domain-confirmation 90DIFG9EEUT8U8R4895Y87H
booking.com TXT onetrust-domain-verification=3fce180bf9e54d5b97a7c9e1ce3cb10c
booking.com TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.booking.com include:spf-0032a203.pphosted.com include:_spf.messagegears.net include:sendgrid.net include:mail.zendesk.com include:spf.logicalware.com include:mailgun.org -all
booking.com NS  ns0.bkngs.com
booking.com NS  ns1.bkngs.com
booking.com NS  ns2.bkngs.com
booking.com NS  ns3.bkngs.com
```

The error I see is:

> Get-DnsServerZone : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The
> argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
> empty, and  then try the command again. At line:6 char:72
>
> - ... rZone -ComputerName $PrimaryDNSServer -Name $DomainNames.Name -ErrorA ...
> - ```
>                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-DnsServerZone], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Get-DnsServerZone   DNS Forward
>     Lookup Zones  does not exist in PRDINTDNS07-VM

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The MX record is not created.

Comment: The Pastebin linked doesnt work properly, add a few example rows to the question instead.

Comment: O, I have just updated the post with the sample CSV file.

Comment: Do you get any error message or what is happening when you are running the script?

Comment: I've updated the code and the error as above.